# SOAP Suds library for Java or Scala

Tags: java, soap, suds

I need to access the "Web Of Science" API, and unfortunately they use the ugly SOAP protocol. It seems they use a lightweight SOAP protocol or library called "Suds".
There is a Suds library for python: https://webkul.com/blog/python-suds-client/

Is there Java or Scala equivalent of this library?